# 450 Error message

Tags: windows, vba, ms-word

I cannot get an original copy of word to open. It only allows me a read only copy. The Doc.Tables.Add... does not seem to work.

I will eventually pass an array to this sub routine, containing data to write to the fields of #the table.  First I have to get it to add tables. I get the #sense that my "Doc" is not recognized.  Any help is appreciated.

```
    Sub InsertTbl()
        Dim wd As Word.Application
        Dim Doc As Word.Document
        Dim fn As String

        fn = "H:\JailData\aaNEW\GTL_Receipts.docx"
        Set wd = New Word.Application
        wd.Visible = True
        Set Doc = wd.Documents.Open(fn)
        MsgBox Doc.Tables.Count
        Doc.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=4

        tblIndx = Doc.Tables.Count
        With Doc.Tables(tblIndx).Application
            .Left = 100
            .Top = 200
        End With
        Doc.Tables(tblIndx).Range.Font.Size = 8
    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? `Tables.Add` returns a `Table` object, so you can declare a `Table` variable and then capture the reference with `Set whatever = Doc.Tables.Add 'with your arguments`.  Also, `Doc.Tables(tblIndx).Application` is the same thing as your `wd` instance.

Comment: Your path indicates a network share. Have you included it in Word's "trusted storage locations"? File=>Options=>Trust Center => Trusted sites... (or similar, I have a localized version of Word)